# Windows domain username formats? NETBDOMAIN\USERNAME and DNSDOMAIN.COM\Username?

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller, internal-dns, wins

I'm running into issues with authentication and mapped network drives across a VPN tunnel. Namely error messages related to not being able to find a domain controller. I suspect this is somehow related to WINS, as DNS lookups seem to be working correctly. In trying to understand the underlying issue, I've across something curious.

In system information (msinfo32.exe) a username shows up in two formats:

1. NETBIOSDOMAIN\My Name   under startup programs
2. DNSDOMAIN.COM\My Name    under Network Connections

What is the difference between these usernames? And how might that relate to stored credentials for the mapped drives, or name resolution for the domain controller?

Comment: `What is the difference between these usernames`. None. ` I suspect this is somehow related to WINS`. WINS hasn't been needed for 18 years.

Comment: `I suspect this is somehow related to WINS` - It's not. `DNS lookups seem to be working correctly` - Seem to be? I'd verify that DNS is **actually** working properly. "**Seem to be**" doesn't inspire much confidence.

Comment: DNS was confimred by successful NSLookup for the domain controller currently listed in the %logonserver% enviroment variable, as well as other resources.

Comment: And this only happens with mapped drives? Can you access other paths? Are those paths from a file server, or are they DFS paths? Have you checked the Windows logs for more errors?

Comment: There is no techical difference in DOMAIN\user and DOMAIN.COM\user. Technically even user@domain.com ("UPN") is the same.

Comment: I just found this answer  - https://serverfault.com/a/371390/505983 seems to clarify the usernames.