# Can ADFS groups be referred to as both DOMAIN\groupname and groupname@DOMAIN?

Tags: adfs, oidc

Does the [near-equivalence](https://serverfault.com/questions/371150/any-difference-between-domain-username-and-usernamedomain-local) between `DOMAIN\username` and `username@DOMAIN` only hold for users or also for groups? In particular, can ADFS clients that request groups as claims with option `Token-Groups - Qualified by Long Domain Name` assume that the format for each entry will be `DOMAIN\groupname`, or do they have to accommodate both styles?